# Deletar arquivo com o nome e o caminho em outro arquivo .bat

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

Preciso desenvolver uma batch que tem que ler os dados em um arquivo.txt, e de acordo com o caminho e nome do arquivo que tenho no txt a batch tem que ir até a pasta e apagar arquivos.

Os dados que tenho nesse arquivo são resultados de uma query sql. 
Para exemplificar o que eu disse:

```
file_name, file_path
abcd, D:/user/desktop/teste123
efgh, D:/user/desktop/folder789
```

A minha batch precisa ler o `file_name` (para saber o que apagar) e `file_path` (para saber onde apagar).

Answer (score 3):

Usando `FOR /F`

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (in.txt) do echo del "%%b/%%a"
Pause
```

Coloquei o comando **`echo`** em frente do comando **`del`**, para ser possível testar a saída do comando.

Veja se esta **ok**, daí é só remover **`echo`** nesta parte `echo del "%%b/%%a"`, ficando assim:

`del "%%b/%%a"`

Answer (score 1):

• Num looping **`for`** usando as variáveis **`%%i & %%j`**

**Aplicadas em: nome  caminho**

**Para o seguinte layout do seu arquivo:**

```bat
abcd, D:/user/desktop/teste123
efgh, D:/user/desktop/folder789
```

• **delete caminho/nome = %%j/%%i**

```bat
@echo off & for /f "delims=,tokens=1,2" %%i in ('type query_sql.log')do if /i not "/.%%i"=="/." del /q /f "%%j\%%i"
```

**#** É possível também usar a **resposta** do **Operador** **[`@Gerhard Barnard`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818749/gerhard-barnard)** para a **mesma pergunta** postada no **[`SatackOverFlow /EN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225597/delete-a-files-with-their-name-and-path-in-another-file-bat#)**, visto que queres **pular**  a primeira linha.

```bat
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %i in ('more +1 my_file.txt ^| findstr /VI /C:"rows affected"')do del "%%j\%%i"
```